# JupyterLab User Settings File

Tags: jupyter-lab

I leverage Docker containers to launch JupyterLabs and would like the ability to apply user settings directly at launch, instead of configuring user settings through the "Advanced Settings Editor" GUI at every container launch.

In reviewing the following pull request, it does seem that this functionality should exist: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/pull/2585

I have not found anything referencing this capability in the JupyterLab documentation, so any leads would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Running `jupyter-lab --generate-config` should generate a config file in `/home/<USER>/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`

Comment: above command is `jupyter lab ...` instead of `jupyter-lab ...`

Comment: @ZekeArneodo, probably this deserves a new question, do you know how to use this file to import preferences in a new (different) jupyterlab?

Comment: As of version 0.32.1 which is the one I have installed, if you port the files /home/$(whoami)/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py and /home/$(whoami)/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json (if exists), you will be porting the configuration, including the set password. If setting up a new install, I would probably run jupyter-lab --generate-config first, so it creates the default locations and config files and replace them with the ones to import.

Comment: This should not be the answer. config and settings are different.

Comment: That is true! Sorry I thought the question was a different one, but there are no edits. So I just answered the wrong question. Should we delete this answer?

Comment: @JeanMonet `jupyter lab` and `jupyter-lab` are the same command

Comment: @蔡宗容 incorrect. Please refer to the documentation: https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started/starting.html#starting-jupyterlab

Comment: @JeanMonet The doc you provided doesn't show anything about the differences between `jupyter lab` and `jupyter-lab`. When a user runs `jupyter lab ... `, it should be redirected to `jupyter-lab` where `lab` is a subcommand

Comment: @JeanMonet the image https://i.imgur.com/273Z9hS.png shows the redirection from `jupyter lab ... ` to `jupyter-lab ... `

Answer (score 20):

Settings for extensions are documented here:

https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/extensions.html#settings

In short, you can supply and `overrides.json` in `<sys-prefix>/share/jupyter/lab/settings` where `<sys-prefix>` can be found by running `jupyter lab path`.

The example from the docs shows an `overrides.json` like this:

```
{
  "@jupyterlab/apputils-extension:themes": {
    "theme": "JupyterLab Dark"
  }
}
```

Comment: The key name of the dictionary entry is taken from the // commented-out header at the top of each section of Advanced Settings Editor. So for instance, to make a change to defaults of the Notebook section, e.g. turning on Record Timing for all users unless they turn it off...

    {
      "@jupyterlab/notebook-extension:tracker": {
        "recordTiming": true
      }
    }

Answer (score 12):

I couldn't find any documentations, however in your folder `~/.jupyter/lab/user-settings/@jupyterlab` if you create a custom notebook configuration (for instance), you will have a file created in `notebook-extension/tracker.jupyterlab-settings`.

You can copy the folder(s) you want to use for each of your container in this location, then when you start a jupyter lab, you should see the custom configuration(s) loaded correctly.

Comment: `jupyter lab path` does show this path. But I'm not sure where to put custom settings for jupyter lab extensions. For example `jupyterlab-execute-time`

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for, too, how to make ExecuteTime's requirements (recordTiming) be on by default for all users, without each user having to make a one-time change in Advanced Settings. In our case, we're using The Littlest JupyterJub, so the path of the file described above by @bsimpson53 is `/opt/tljh/user/share/jupyter/lab/settings/overrides.json`. The folder `settings` may or may not exist, so you may have to `mkdir` that, and then create a file overrides.json inside it.

`{
    "@jupyterlab/notebook-extension:tracker": {
        "recordTiming": true
    }
}`

Comment: @JeffSaxe I have been absolutely losing my mind trying to figure out how to do this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In `/usr/local/share/jupyter/lab/schemas/@jupyterlab`, you can find all default settings.

And in `notebook-extension/tracker.json`, you can find the `recordTiming`.

Change the default value will help.

Answer (score 0):

**This list of options can be generated by running the following and hitting enter:**

`python3 -m jupyterlab_server --help-all`

Using this you can see the configuration on terminal screen itself.