# Enable extension manager by default

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

As per the [jupyter lab documentation](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/extensions.html#using-the-extension-manager) to enable extension manager you need to go to setting menu and enable it.
Is there a configuration I can set in order for jupyter lab to lunch with extension manager enabled by default?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48950670/jupyterlab-user-settings-file

check this issue, and #2 Adonis answer worked