# Enable jupyterlab extensions by default via docker

Tags: docker, jupyter-lab

I launched jupyterlab 3 via a Dockerfile which includes some extensions like `mathjax3-extension`. If i run it, i need to enable the extension manager first before the extensions are working e.g. latex is rendered. Is there a way to include a Docker command to enable the extension manager by default? I found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48950670/jupyterlab-user-settings-file), but cannot translate it to a Docker command.

Answer (score 1):

You can place a pre-built settings file in the user's directory at `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`, or set systemwide defaults in `/etc/jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`.

For an example implementation, see the [jupyter project's base-notebook docker image](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/base-notebook), which sets system defaults by copying the `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file you can view in the root directory.

This file is then copied into place [within the dockerfile (L155)](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/blob/master/base-notebook/Dockerfile#L155):

```
# Currently need to have both jupyter_notebook_config and jupyter_server_config to support classic and lab
COPY jupyter_notebook_config.py /etc/jupyter/
```

Comment: Thanks, i need to study the image first, to know how to manipulate it, but seems to be the thing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a settings file Jupyter Lab looks to check that you have read the warning about extensions and agreed to enable them. You need to add this file.

Add a line to your docker:

```
COPY ./plugin.jupyterlab-settings /home/$USER/.jupyter/lab/user-settings/@jupyterlab/extensionmanager-extension/
```

The above command assumes:

1. `$USER` is assumed to be defined earlier in your dockerfile.
2. `plugin.jupyterlab-settings` is a file with the following contents:

   ```
   {
       // Extension Manager
       // @jupyterlab/extensionmanager-extension:plugin
       // Extension manager settings.
       // *********************************************

       // Disclaimed Status
       // Whether the user understand that extensions managed through this interface run arbitrary code that may be dangerous
       "disclaimed": true
   }
   ```