# How can JupyterLab load notebook.json or custom.js when JupyterLab launching?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I want to have JupyterLab launch and load custom settings and overwrite advanced settings automacally.

But I can't do it although I tried three method `notebook.json`/`custom.js`/`config.js`.

How can I do it?

### My Environment

#### Versions

- python: 3.9.1

  - jupyter-client                    6.1.12
  - jupyter-contrib-core              0.3.3
  - jupyter-contrib-nbextensions      0.5.1
  - jupyter-core                      4.7.1
  - jupyter-highlight-selected-word   0.2.0
  - jupyter-latex-envs                1.4.6
  - jupyter-nbextensions-configurator 0.4.1
  - jupyter-packaging                 0.10.1
  - jupyter-server                    1.6.4
  - jupyterlab                        3.0.14
  - jupyterlab-pygments               0.1.2
  - jupyterlab-server                 2.5.0

#### Directory

```
├ ~/
  ├ .jupyter/
    ├ nbconfig/
      ├ notebook.json
    ├ config/
      ├ config.js
    ├ custom/
      ├ custom.js
```

#### Settings

```
// ~/.jupyter/nbconfig/notebook.json
{
    "load_extensions": {
        "codefolding/main": true
    },
    "MarkdownCell": {
        "cm_config": {
            "autoClosingBrackets": true,
            "lineNumbers": true,
            "lineWrapping": false
        }
    },
    "CodeCell": {
        "cm_config": {
            "lineNumbers": true,
            "lineWrapping": true
        }
    },
    "Cell": {
        "cm_config": {
            "lineNumbers": true,
            "lineWrapping": true
        }
    },
    "codeCellConfig": {
        "cm_config": {
            "tabSize": 4,
            "insertSpaces": true,
            "readOnly": false,
            "autoClosingBrackets": true,
            "matchBrackets": true,
            "lineNumbers": true,
            "lineWrapping": "wordWrapColumn",
            "wordWrapColumn": 95
        }
    }
}
```

```
// ~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js or ~/.jupyter/config/config.js
var cm_config = require('notebook/js/cell').Cell.options_default.cm_config;
cm_config.tabSize = 4;
cm_config.readOnly = false;
cm_config.lineNumbers = true;
cm_config.linWrapping = true;
// cm_config.wordWrapColumn = 95;
cm_config.autoClosingBrackets = true;
```

Comment: You seem to be using Notebook settings for JupyterLab. You should be using [overrides.json](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/directories.html#overrides-json) instead (and the JSON schema is completely different from what you use above, but all have their corresponding entries).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JupyterLab User Settings File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48950670/jupyterlab-user-settings-file)

Comment: @krassowski
`override.json` may be help me. but I can't find its options for example linenumbers.
Would you tell me web sites tells options of `override.json`?

Comment: You basically need to go to the Advanced Settings Editor and find it there; the top-level key is the name of the extension (everything is an extension in JupyterLab), you can find it in the "System Defaults" panel (in the comment near the top).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! Thank you for your advice, @krassowski!

Now, I can load  Jupyterlab advanced settings when launching with `{sys.prefix}/share/jupyter/lab/settings/override.json` like below.

```
{
    "@jupyterlab/apputils-extension:themes": {
        "theme": "JupyterLab Dark"
    },
    "@jupyterlab/notebook-extension:tracker": {
        "markdownCellConfig": {
            "autoClosingBrackets": true,
            "lineNumbers": true,
            "lineWrap": "off"
        },
        "rawCellConfig": {
            "lineNumbers": true,
            "lineWrap": "wordWrapColumn",
            "wordWrapColumn": 130
        },
        "codeCellConfig": {
            "tabSize": 4,
            "insertSpaces": true,
            "readOnly": false,
            "codeFolding": false,
            "autoClosingBrackets": true,
            "matchBrackets": true,
            "lineNumbers": true,
            "lineWrap": "wordWrapColumn",
            "wordWrapColumn": 130
        }
    }
}
```